# XtraFinder makes Finder windows not all restore

Tags: macos, finder

I love XtraFinder, but it seems to prevent all windows from restoring when Finder restarts (e.g., after typing `killall Finder` in the terminal).

I'm on Yosemite (10.10.5), and Finder restores all windows and tabs when I reboot or relaunch it *without* XtraFinder. However, when it boots *with* XtraFinder, no windows open at all (although Finder has started), and when I click on the Finder icon, it opens one window from the previous session (always the same), but not the other ones.

This happens whether or not the `save open tabs when quitting Finder` option in XtraFinder is enabled.

How to have the original session restore behavior with XtraFinder enabled?

Comment: Which folder does it open? (When you click on it)

Comment: It's a window with with a few tabs to personal folders. They always get saved and restored properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone. I realized the OS X setting for restoring windows was disabled. I enabled it, and Finder windows are now restored properly (even though the XtraFinder option `save open tabs when quitting Finder` is disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Seems, from the duration it is left unanswered, this is yet to be worked on. For the time being, as a work around, save the window with all its tabs. And reopen the same window after restart.